# Sticky :hover persistent on stylus

Tags: css

I am using the following prevent sticky :hover on touch devices. BUT, this does not work on stylus devices with pens.

```
@media(hover:hover){ 
 .test:hover{color:red;}
}
```

I would like :hover to work on stylus devices with the pen but I don't want sticky buttons when people use their fingers.

Is there a solution for stylus devices?

Answer (score 0):

Fine pointers like a mouse or stylus pen:

```
@media(pointer:fine){
 .test:hover{color:red;}
}
```